# A php error was encoutered in my project in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I want to set up my first project in CodeIgniter which includes a database.
I've made the proper configurations for database like shown in this tutorial: [Everything You Need to Get Started With CodeIgniter](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/everything-you-need-to-get-started-with-codeigniter--net-2634).

I have created my database in phpMyadmin.
When try to access the project in my localhost this is the error:
[image]
After changing password from 'root' to ' ' now the error is this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Model' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\models\diploma_model.php on line 2
```

This is my model cpde:

```html
<?php
class diploma_model extends Model {
 
    function diploma_model()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::Model();
    }
     
    function getData()

        {
            //Query the data table for every record and row
            $query = $this->db->get('data');
             
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                //show_error('Database is empty!');
            }else{
                return $query->result();
            }
        }
 
}
?>
```

Im new at codeIgniter. Can someone explain why this error occurs? Thanks!

Comment: You tried to follow tutorial 7 years old. That is the first problem. Find some tutorials not older than 2013./2014. Most important is security component regarding the difference of old code and new code/FWs approach. When you are there already, read [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet) about security. :)

Comment: Did you try any of the answers below?

Comment: class diploma_model extends CI_Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tutorial that you have read is very out of date. The current codeigniter website is [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/)

It would be worth reading through [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/welcome.html)

This is the correct way for CI model and [anatomy-of-a-model](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model) I think because you just extend Model and no CI_Model

And your construct is wrong to.

On autoload.php I would autoload database.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Filename Diploma_model.php

```
<?php    

class Diploma_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {

    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}

function getData() {
  $query = $this->db->get('data');

  // This > means greater. So will return results if any found!

  if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

     return $query->result();

     //return $query->result_array();

   } else {

       return false;

    }
  }

}
```

Loading of the [model](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model)

```
<?php 

class Example extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('diploma_model');
   }

   public function index() {
      $data['lists'] = $this->diploma_model->getData();

      $this->load->view('someview', $data);
   }

}
```

The CI User guide for [models](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

Answer (score 1):

go to application/config/database.php file, and set the user, pass and whatever you want to the database configuration.

You will see something like this:

```
(...)
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'database_name',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
(...)
```

Comment: ok, well I don't see anything wrong in your code. I think that you set up a wrong password in your database.php file.

Comment: you should follow the tips that give you @wolfgang1983